# v-model não funciona no vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Em um simples teste em Vue.Js, seguindo o exemplo da documentação, o span nunca exibe o dado selecionado pelo select.

O select é montado pelo vue, porém a variável `select` não é espelhada.

```
    <div class="row" id='vue'>
       <select v-model="selected">
         <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
           @{{ option.text }}
         </option>
       </select>
       <span>Selected: @{{ selected }}</span>
    </div>

   <script>
     new Vue({
        el: '#vue',
        data: {
            selected: 'A',
            options: [{
                    text: 'One',
                    value: 'A'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Two',
                    value: 'B'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Three',
                    value: 'C'
                }
            ]
        }
    })
   </script>
```

Estou utilizando `@{{` pois é um implementação no Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri que isso é algum conflito com o JQMigrate e só está travando os selects, não tem nada haver com o vuejs.

Para descobrir isso, testei o v-mode em outro elemento e funcionou, assim como se eu remover o JQMigrate, o próprio select funciona normalmente.

Não solucionei o conflito ainda, mas como a questão se trata do vuejs, vou considerar resolvido e deixar aqui para facilitar a vida do próximo.

No console, há este alerta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]